# How does a Router/Modem obtain the Port Number from an IP Datagram?

Tags: networking, router, tcp

The IP datagram header is a layer below the TCP segment which contains information on the port.

Therefore before a firewall can inspect a port number, must the IP datagrams be rebuilt into the TCP segment?

Does this mean a buffer of IP datagrams awaits an entire TCP segment before the Port is read?

Comment: Also note that unless there is a MTU downgrade somewhere in the path, causing a fragment, Packets-to-Segments is 1-to-1. If the packet is fragged, the entire fragment is usually buffered until the rest of the packets containing the fragments arrive. Also note that at a binary level, the data is just a stream, and encapsulated headers occur after their lower layer parent, so "decapsulating" a datagram is just reading past the end of the current layers header, into its data field. Theres not really any work to decapsulating a stream, just cutting off the beginning and the end for a known length.

Comment: you only need the first 4bytes of the TCP segment to get both the source and destination ports.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address and TCP ports are present in every TCP/IP packet.  The minimum header an IP packet can have is 20 bytes, which includes the IP addresses.  The minimum size of the TCP header is also 20 bytes, the first four of which are the source and destination ports.

So there is no need to wait for anything, the port and addresses will always be present in a TCP/IP packet, otherwise it isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore before a firewall can inspect a port number, must the IP datagrams be rebuilt into the TCP segment?

A TCP segment contains the source port and destination port as the first two fields in its header.  The header begins any TCP segment.

[image]

So not really, the firewall can gather the info from the first 4 bytes received.

Answer (score 0):

The IP datagram includes the TCP datagram in its Data part. The router has to receive at least 24 bytes to get the source and destination ports (called also TCP addresses) if the IP header is of minimal size (20 bytes).

The inclusion of datagrams is shown below:

[image: Inclusion of datagrams]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).